# How do I obtain an access and refresh token for a google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

Hi I have a very simple Google Apps Script, i.e. one that is created when in Google Drive and click create and then script.

What I would like to be able to do is have users authenticate using the oauth 2 protocol, receive the authorisation code and exchange that for an access token and refresh token. This requirement is for an IPhone app so I would rather save the refresh token so users do not have to login repeatedly.

My issue is that I do seem be able to get the access and refresh token, I can see the client_id of the app in the url returned from the authentication step, however I believe I also need client_secret to request the access and refresh token from:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.

I'm asking it this even possible, if so do you know of any examples and if not could you recommend a different approach (perhaps use an application specific password).

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain this from the Oauth Playground.

[Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)